# Limit of a sequence with inequalities or special limits.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

**Exercise.** Compute the following limit:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(n^8+2016^n)\Bigg(1-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n!}}\Bigg).
$$

**Solution.** I know the limit is $0$ (let's say because $n!$ is "faster" than any power and any exponential). I am looking for a nice way to show it, i.e. through some special limits or inequalities.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $$1-a=\frac{1-a^2}{1+a}$$

Comment: **Hint :** As $n\rightarrow\infty ,\,\,\,\left( \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n!}}\right) \approx 1 $

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit I cannot really see how this should help, because the OP has already observed that the second factor of the product will converge to $0$ very fast.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek $(1 - \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n!}} ) \approx 0 \iff \left( \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n!}}\right) \approx 1$

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit as I said the OP has already made this observation and is asking for some justification that helps him to prove that the limit of the product is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

We can use that by binomial approximation

$$\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n!}} \sim 1-\frac1{2n!}$$

$$(n^8+2016^n)\left(1-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n!}}\right)\sim \frac{n^8+2016^n}{2n!}$$

or as an alternative

$$(n^8+2016^n)\left(1-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n!}}\right)=\frac{n^8+2016^n}{n!}\cdot \frac{1-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n!}}}{\frac1{n!}}$$

and

$$\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n!}}}{\frac1{n!}}=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n!}}}{\frac1{n!}}\frac{1+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n!}}}{1+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n!}}}=\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n!}}} \to \frac12$$

Answer (score 1):

Using *equivalents* enables you to remove unrelated details:

We know that $\;\sqrt{1+x}\sim_0 1+\frac12 x+o(x)$, so
$$1-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n!}}=\frac1{2(n!)}+o\Bigl(\frac1{n!}\Bigr) $$ 
and $n^8+2016^n\sim_{n\to\infty}2016^n$, so
$$(n^8+2016^n)\biggl(1-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n!}}\biggr)\sim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2016^n}{2(n!)}\to 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

A rough squeezing is also helpful here:

$$0\leq(n^8+2016^n)\Bigg(1-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n!}}\Bigg)= \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n!}}}\frac{n^8+2016^n}{n!}\leq \frac{2\cdot 2016^n}{n!}$$
$$\stackrel{n>4032}{\leq}\underbrace{\frac{2\cdot 2016^{4032}}{4032!}}_{=C}\cdot\frac 1{2^{n-4032}}\stackrel{n\to \infty}{\rightarrow}0$$